# PHP Date Problem

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have used `date("mm/dd/yyyy")` format to insert get date in PHP but when i saved it in MySQL it just saved 00/00/0000

Comment: the result of `date("mm/dd/yyyy")` is `0404/2828/11111111`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not correct formatting for date: http://www.php.net/date

`date("m/d/Y");` is what you're looking for.

Comment: date format should be `YYYY-mm-dd` for mysql. mysql does not accept except this `YYYY-mm-dd`

Comment: d/m/Y might be correct for PHP but to insert into a mysql DATE field dbase it ought to be Y-m-d - and you can enter a date such as that into DATETIME field and mysql is smart enough to append the necessary 00:00:00

Comment: As they said, you actually want this: date("Y-m-d"); if you're saving to DATE. Another option though is just a simply NOW()

Answer (score 1):

Your date format is wrong. Try `date('m/d/Y');`

Answer (score 1):

```
date("mm/dd/yyyy")
```

doesn't do what you think it does. Check out [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and you can find you probably meant

```
date("m/d/Y");                         // 03.10.2011
```

Comment: No, He needs `date("Y/m/d"); `

Comment: Depends on whatever is happening after the call, doesn't it?

Comment: he clearly said that date is wrongly entering in mysql. Is that not enough?

Comment: It also states that it is saved as `00/00/0000`. Your `Y/m/d` would not fit in a 2-2-4 format? Maybe something with localisation?

Comment: Thank you guys It help me out to fix problem.

Answer (score 1):

date("mm/dd/yyyy") this format is not supported by the mysql.as mysql supports the date format in yyyy/mm/dd.
so try to enter in this format.The 0 error would be removed.

Answer (score 0):

for mysql valid `DATETIME` value must be like that : `date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`, for `DATE` must be `date("Y-m-d");`

Answer (score 0):

Enter the date in the normal format dd-mm-yyyy bt when u extract the date value from the databse sql thn use the function:
 $date=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date1));